# Why Python zipfile module creates full path inside the zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I need to zip all files in a given directory(inside test1) into a zip file.

My code is

```
import zipfile
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('/media/test/test1/'+'my_zip.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
#Here I mentioned the path for specifying where the zip file should created
path='/media/test/test1/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if not str(file).endswith('.zip'):
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
zipf.close()
```

This gives the output of **my_zip.zip**

When I open this, it contains each subfolder like **media>test>test1>files in test 1**

But I don't want this media>test>test1. How to achieve that?

Comment: I think you can fix this by specifying an `arcname=file` parameter to `.write()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not pass the name that should be used in the archive, then `zipfile` uses the path that was passed into `write()`

Try this:

```
 zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file), 
            arcname=os.path.join(root.replace(path, '', 1), file))
```

Comment: u mean second line should be like this?
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile()

Comment: @Vanjith  No.  Use the lines I provided in place of the `zipf.write(...)` on your eighth line.